# Disable Panels at Startup from Custom Config Location

Tags: qgis, gui, panel

I'm trying to start QGIS 2.8 with the minimal GUI possible so I can reskin QGIS for a custom plugin. Unfortunately I'm not able to get rid of the Layers and Overview panels when saving the configuration into a custom location when starting QGIS with the options --configpath  --optionspath. Everything else is customizable, I'm able to hide all the menus, but even though all the panels are marked as false in the QGISCUSTOMIZATION2.ini they still show up as displayed in the picture.

The funny thing is that if I let the application store the values in the registry all the panels are disabled fine, but because this has to be shipped to approximately 40 - 50 clients I'd rather accomplish this with the QGISCUSTOMIZATION2.ini and the QGIS2.ini files rather than using the registry.

Any ideas?

[image: Panel Problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. The things that I thought were called Panels are called Docks.

Either I'm blind or there's no trace of them in the customization settings menu. Nevertheless if you paste the following lines into the QGISCUSTOMIZATION2.ini file, the docks are gone for good.

```
Docks=false
Docks\Browser=false
Docks\GPSInformation=false
Docks\Legend=false
Docks\MessageLog=false
Docks\Overview=false
Docks\Layers=false
Docks\Undo=false
```